# Download failed in anchor tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, anchor

I am using acnchor tag to download file on click of it but on click the file fails to download and shows Failed-Network error in in chrome browser.
I changed my anchor tag on different ways but non of them working

```
     <td><a href="@file.FilePath">@file.FileName</a></td>
     <td><a href="@file.FilePath" download>@file.FileName</a></td>
     <td><a href="@file.FilePath" download=@file.FileName>@file.FileName</a></td>
```

What is problem in it?

Comment: what does `FilePath` have?

Comment: FilePath have the path where document exist like D:\TFS\MyProject\sampleWeb\Freelancers\9\1\

Comment: you will have to do some sort of serving it over http - theres plenty of examples of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a client-server issue. That path exists on the server, but the download is initiated by the client. The client doesn't have access to the server's filesystem, so it fails. If you need stuff in that directory available for download, create a virtual directory under your site that points to that path, then link the user to the file under the virtual directory, e.g.:

```
<a href="/myvirtualdirectory/myfile.foo">Click me!</a>
```